# Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I've written a function to sort player objects by one of their fields here:

```
function [ sortedPlayers ] = sortPlayers(players)
%sorts player objects by rating
    playersFields = fieldnames(players);
    playersCell = struct2cell(players);
    sz = size(playersCell);

    playersCell = reshape(playersCell, sz(1), []);
    playersCell = playersCell';
    playersCell = sortrows(playersCell, -3);

    playersCell = reshape(playersCell', sz);
    sortedPlayers = cell2struct(playersCell, playersFields, 1);
end
```

When it runs, I get this error:

```
    Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in sortPlayers (line 4)
    playersFields = fieldnames(players);

Error in getTeamPlayers (line 16)
    teamPlayers = sortPlayers(teamPlayers);

Error in masterSimulate (line 13)
    firstTeam = getTeamPlayers(team_dict, firstTeamName);

Error in mainMenu (line 25)
                masterSimulate(team_dict);

Error in main (line 18)
mainMenu(team_dict, allPlayers);
```

I've googled around and most of the time this type of error is caused by a function being named differently from the file its in.  However, 'fieldnames' is a built-in function.  I run:

```
which fieldnames -all
```

and get back:

```
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/toolbox/matlab/datatypes/@struct/fieldnames)             % struct method
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/toolbox/matlab/datatypes/@opaque/fieldnames)             % opaque method
fieldnames is a built-in method                                                                    % meta.PackageList method
fieldnames is a built-in method
...
```

Any idea what's going on here?  I don't think I changed anything within my `sortPlayers` function so I'm pretty lost re: why it's no longer working properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the function/script that calls `sortPlayers`, we can't determine why the argument it received is a `double`.

Comment: The error is because `players` is a double. You'll just have to trace back through your code to wherever it is defined or modified.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the argument that you pass to your function when you call it is not of class `struct`, a user defined class or a Java class, but something else (`double` maybe?).

To test the class of the argument, just add at the beginning of the function:

```
 fprintf(1, '"players" has the type "%s".\n', class(players));
```

and then call your function again (or run the application that calls it for you).

Comment: Yeah, the last time 'sortPlayers' gets called, its argument is of type 'double' :( I've updated my question to include the full error message.  Still not sure why what's passed in is of type 'double' and not 'struct'

Comment: @bclayman Is really difficult to figure out what is wrong with code only from the stack trace messages. One way is to configure MATLAB to stop on all errors. When the error occurs you can look in the context of all the functions on the stack. Look at "Examples and How To" here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Comment: Just followed what they say in the link you provided.  I get that players = [] and that players is of class double...very strange

Comment: @bclayman I'm sorry, but I realize that one cannot answer the question you asked as it is. Without the code for the `getTeamPlayers` one cannot see how the argument for `sortPlayers` is built in the first place. The thing is: your mistake is rather upstream `sortPlayers`, so the code from those functions is significant, while the code of `sortPlayers` is not (it just throws an error for expecting a type and not getting it). Do you want me to delete the answer? Also, I would recommend either changing the question or deleting it, because is not well defined as it is.